# Ios version of app works, but Android fails due to no suitable constructor found for AccessToken for React Native App

Tags: android, react-native, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

As mentioned in the title, the Ios version of this app works fine on a physical device.  However, when I try to build it on an android device, I get an error

```
error: no suitable constructor found for AccessToken(String,String,String,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>)
constructor AccessToken.AccessToken(String,String,String,Collection<String>,Collection<String>,AccessTokenSource,Date,Date,Date) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor AccessToken.AccessToken(Parcel) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

This error is highlighted in FBGraphRequestModule.java file, specifically in this method

```
    private void setConfig(GraphRequest graphRequest, ReadableMap configMap) {
            if (configMap == null) {
                graphRequest.setAccessToken(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken());
                return;
            }
            if (configMap.hasKey("parameters")) {
                graphRequest.setParameters(buildParameters(configMap.getMap("parameters")));
            }
            if (configMap.hasKey("httpMethod")) {


graphRequest.setHttpMethod(HttpMethod.valueOf(configMap.getString("httpMethod")));
    }
    if (configMap.hasKey("version")) {
        graphRequest.setVersion(configMap.getString("version"));
    }
    if (configMap.hasKey("accessToken")) {
        graphRequest.setAccessToken(new AccessToken(
            configMap.getString("accessToken"),
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getApplicationId(),
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId(),
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null));
    } else {
        graphRequest.setAccessToken(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken());
    }
}
```

More specifically,

```
if (configMap.hasKey("accessToken")) {
            graphRequest.setAccessToken(new AccessToken(
                configMap.getString("accessToken"),
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getApplicationId(),
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId(),
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null));
```

My Java skills are nonexistent, so I have no idea how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same issue today as well, upgrading `react-native-fbsdk` to 0.8.0 seems to fix it

Comment: how do you do this...my gradle says `implementation project(':react-native-fbsdk')` how do i specify a version?

Comment: @ewizard You specify the version in your `package.json` file, and the import (i.e., `implementation project(':react-native-fbsdk')`) doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

I had also that issue today and solved by modifying the package to have the last parameter - dataAccessExpirationTime.

```
new AccessToken(
            configMap.getString("accessToken"),
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getApplicationId(),
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId(),
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null)
```

You will see this issue in FBGraphRequestModule.java and Utility.java file.
So please fix both files.

Comment: I'd rather suggest upgrading `react-native-fbsdk` to 0.8.0

Comment: my Utility.java looks like this `new AccessToken(
                accessTokenMap.getString("accessToken"),
                accessTokenMap.getString("applicationID"),
                accessTokenMap.getString("userID"),
                reactArrayToStringList(accessTokenMap.getArray("permissions")),
                reactArrayToStringList(accessTokenMap.getArray("declinedPermissions")),
                accessTokenSource,
                expirationTime,
                lastRefreshTime,
                null` - you only need to add `null` to the end.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, my understanding is that react-native-fbsdk v0.7.0 had not locked the minor version of the dependency com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk. see `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4+'` in `node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/`. Facebook released a new version `4.38.1`, previously known working version was  `4.37.0`. Because the minor version was not locked the newer version of `com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4` was pulled down and caused breakage.

Upgrading to react-native-fbsdk v0.8.0 and `com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.38.1` changes the binary package, forcing us to do a full app update ( opposed to just a UI content updated via Code-Push ). We try to limit binary releases because they're larger and our users aren't forced to update the app.

Force resolving the version of `com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4+` worked for us

In the root build.gradle file add or merge the following

```
allprojects {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.37.0'
        }
    }
}
```

[Ref](https://blog.danlew.net/2015/09/09/dont-use-dynamic-versions-for-your-dependencies/) : This article describes some of the downsides to having dynamic dependancies. I suggest when you include a new module lock all the dynamic dependancies. This will help ensure every rebuild results in a predictable output.