# react-native-fbsdk error with FBGraphRequestModule and Utility AccessToken constructor not found

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

After upgrading Facebook SDK to 4.37.0, I met Issue with react-native-fbsdk package.
When I tried to run the android app with react-native run-android, It is showing:

> react-native-fbsdk no suitable constructor found for
>   AccessToken(String,String,String,,,,,)

I'm not sure what to do next.
Please help me with this.

Comment: You can see the solution here.
[StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52965549/8863446)

Comment: @SergeyVetrov Thanks buddy :)