# react-native-fbsdk 0.8.0 package com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk does not exist

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I've tried to upgrade the react-native-fbsdk from 0.7.0 to 0.8.0 but the react-native run-android command does not working anymore.

> :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
>   C:\Dev\react-native\imnews\android\app\src\main\java\com\imnews\MainApplication.java:10: error: package com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk does not exist
>   import com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBSDKPackage;
>                                             ^
>   C:\Dev\react-native\imnews\android\app\src\main\java\com\imnews\MainApplication.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
>               new FBSDKPackage(mCallbackManager),
>                   ^
>     symbol: class FBSDKPackage

This is the reason why I'd like to upgrade to this version:
[Ios version of app works, but Android fails due to no suitable constructor found for AccessToken for React Native App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52961670/ios-version-of-app-works-but-android-fails-due-to-no-suitable-constructor-found)

I've noticed, there is no build directory in node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android.

Used react-native version: react-native@0.57.3

Could somebody help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official bug report helped me to fix this issue: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/260814197942050/?disable_redirect=0

copy-pasted the resolution from the link above - you need to add this to android/build.gradle:

```
def versionOverrides = [
        "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk": "4.37.0",
]

allprojects {
        repositories {
                ...
        }
        configurations.all {
                resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
                        def overrideVersion = versionOverrides[details.requested.group + ":" + details.requested.name]

                        if (overrideVersion != null && details.requested.version != overrideVersion) {
                                details.useVersion overrideVersion
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working for me but olny with react-native-fbsdk@0.7.0. So it can't resolve the "com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk does not exist" issue in case of 0.8.0 version, but the original issue was resolved. So thanks a lot.